# Can't see published ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ftp

I published my finalized ASP.NET MVC 4 web application through FTP using Visual Studio 2012 publishing method. My webhost is Strato.de.

The problem is that when I try to access the website's domain, it says "This domain is now reserved, but no content was uploaded". I checked the ftp server using Filezilla, and all the published files are there. I really don't know why I can't see the website.

Here is a snapshot of the files from Filezilla:

http://i60.tinypic.com/zjxle1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like the "splash" page or default web site on your domain provider. Many providers like GoDaddy want you to also buy web hosting from them, so they initially set your DNS records to a temporary shared hosting-type account with a default website inside. Make sure your DNS records/namespace servers are set to your actual hosting provider.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on how to do that ??
My knowledge in ASP.Net is still pretty limited.

Comment: If this is the case, it has nothing at all to do with ASP.NET. This is basic domain stuff. If you need help setting the DNS records/nameservers for your domain, the best place to seek that is with your domain provider. Read their documentation/help sections.

Comment: Are there any extra details that could help?? The site and documentation are in German, and my German is pretty rusty.